# how to check if a hidden value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net app where I utilize hidden fields to store values (if need be).

So on the designer side I have this..

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdDDAPDischargeDate" runat="server" />
```

In my C# code I either assign a value to it or leave it as is, so basically something along the lines...

```
if ( condition.........) 
{
 hdDDAPDischargeDate.Value.ToString()== '10/23/2017'
}
```

But in many cases I don't assign a value, so later on when i go to check what the value of it is, i can't get it to hit the `ELSE` part of the `if` statement

I tried:

```
if (hdDDAPDischargeDate.Value != null)

if (hdDDAPDischargeDate.Value.ToString != null)
```

But in both cases it thinks there's a value in the field, or I'm basically checking it wrong

If i hover over the field, it simply shows `""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden fields can't be null, which makes sense if you think about the way they are represented in the HTTP request.

Try checking for an empty string instead:

```
if (hdDDAPAdmissionDate.Value != "")
{
    //Foo
}
```

If for some reason you don't believe me or are not sure, you can always check both:

```
if (hdDDAPAdmissionDate.Value != null && hdDDAPAdmissionDate.Value != "")
{
    //Foo
}
```

Or better yet:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdDDAPAdmissionDate.Value))
{
    //Foo
}
```